# UPS any of the indicator lights not turning on

Tags: battery, ups

I have a prolink UPS pro700 model. I could not use it for around 4 to 5 months ( left alone unused ) and when I try to plug it in and turn it on, non of the indicator lights are illuminating. I know probably the battery would have fully discharged since left unused for a long time, but is it normal for the UPS to not to illuminate any of the indicator lights even when connected to the wall power socket ? 
I am planning to replace the UPS battery, but it will be in vain if there is any problem with the UPS itself. 
So how do I know whether the problem is in the UPS itself or will it work fine if I change the UPS battery ? 
by the way I have checked the fuse and it is in good condition. Appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/343833/prolink-pro700-enerhome.html?page=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dead battery, most of the UPS will not work and even would not start when directly plugged to power socket. This means there is no any indication of lights or any alarming sounds - non of the indicator lights will illuminate.
Once you replace the battery with a new one, it will start working...!!